# R-package installation from GitHub: changes when R package is in a subdir and C++ code in root

Tags: c++, r, github, devtools, r-package

Installation of my R package from GitHub fails when using the `devtools::install_github` function, while the package is in a subdirectory and the C++ code is located at root.

The repository can be found here: https://github.com/Blunde1/gbtorch

The master branch has the C++ code located in the R package folder. However, as I want to build a Python package later, it makes sense to move the C++ header files to the root. I modified this in a new branch: https://github.com/Blunde1/gbtorch/tree/Restructuring-Header-Files

Locally, this works after modifying the `Makevars` files with 
`PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include`
being changed to
`PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../../inst/include`
I therefore assume a clone and manual installation should work, but I want this to be easy and hope that installation using `devtools::install_github` will be possible.

I am most likely ignorant of something, as this is not a new problem. I researched (read "googled") and found that the devtools team indeed has thought of this: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/64 which led to the `subdir` argument in `devtools::install_github`.

Here it seems the issue is solved, but still, the solution with `subdir` does not work for me:

This works: master branch, C++ located in R-package folder

```r
devtools::install_github("Blunde1/gbtorch", ref="master", subdir = "R-package")
```

This fails: new development branch, C++ code not located at R-package folder

```r
devtools::install_github("Blunde1/gbtorch", ref="Restructuring-Header-Files", subdir = "R-package")
```

The above command gives the following error:

`gbtorch.cpp:8:23: fatal error: gbtorch.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "gbtorch.hpp"`

If the header files' location path is not set in the `Makevars` file, then where? Is it possible that some `configure` file might do the trick?

Any ideas on how to fix this? Any help on the subject is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most likely your header files are not part of the R package that is created from the `R-package` sub-directory. See [how xgboost does it](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/Makefile#L237-L260) for an alternative, but note that it does not work with `devtools::install_gihub` either. One alternative would be [drat](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat).

Comment: @RalfStubner Thank you for pointing me to xgboost and letting me know of drat! The cause is most likely what you describe with the header files. Do you know if it is possible to write a configure file that, before the build, will e.g. copy the header files into the R-package sub-directory? The concept of configure files is new to me (as of today) and I am just now trying to understand how this works.

Comment: The `configure` script is part of the package and runs during the installation (`R CMD INSTALL`). That is to late for package building (`R CMD build`). In principle you could use a `configure` script to download the C++ headers into the package, but that feels a strange to me.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on `configure`! In that case I suppose I will look at the xgboost alternative that you proposed (and give up on installations via `devtools::install_github`, and instead create a version for CRAN and/or drat). I am surprised this does not work more easily, as it is exactly the same problem as for [the original issue](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/64#issue-3300749) leading to the `subdir` argument. This was my first stackoverflow question, thank you for answering and making it a learning experience for me!

Comment: I think the crucial part in that issue is *R subfolder of my-uber-project repository is CRAN-stallable*, which is not the case for you.